# What's my math assignment?

Tags: code-golf

## The Challenge

I always write my math assignments down in the same way. For example:

```
pg. 420: #25, 50-56, 90
pg. 26: #50-60 evens, 70-80 odds, 90-99 3s
pg. 69: #12, 16, 18, 37
```

But I need you to tell me the individual problem numbers. For example:

```
input: 
pg. 420: #25, 50-56, 90

output:
25, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 90
```

Here are the rules for telling me my problem numbers:

The assignment always starts with `pg. (number): #`, feel free to discard it.

Each group of problems is separated by a comma, and different patterns mean different things.

A single number (`4, 6, 7438, 698236`) just means that one problem is in the assignment.

Two numbers with a dash between them means those two numbers and all integers between. For example, `1-6` would become `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

If two numbers have a dash between them, then there's a word, there is a special rule for the numbers.

If the word is `evens`, then all even numbers between the two are included (`1-6 evens -> 2, 4, 6`).

If the word is `odds`, then all odd numbers between the two are included (`1-6 odds -> 1, 3, 5`).

If the word is `3s`, then all numbers where `n mod 3 = 0` between the two are included (`1-6 3s -> 3, 6`);

### Test Examples: (inputs then outputs)

```
pg. 1: #1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3

pg. 82: #76, 84-87, 91, 94-100 evens, 103-112 3s
76, 84, 85, 86, 87, 91, 94, 96, 98, 100, 103, 106, 109, 112

pg. 9001: #9000-9002 odds
9001
```

This is code-golf, so your score is the number of bytes.

Comment: Would stuff like "every other odd/even" be a valid input? Or "every other problem"?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Those wouldn't be valid input currently; do you think they should be?

Comment: No, just wondering.

Comment: I feel like we've had this challenge before.

Comment: Closely related: [Tell me how many math problems I have to do!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51189)

Comment: @Dennis TBH, that's just straight up a duplicate. This question does not differ significantly enough IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES7), 138 bytes

```js
F=s=>s.replace(/.*#|(\d+)-?(\d+)? ?(\d|\w*)s?/g,(_,a,b,c)=>b?[for(i of Array(b-a--+1))if(++a*c?(b-a)%c<1:!c||a%2==c>'f')a].join`, `:a||'')
```

```js
F=s=>s.replace(/.*#|(\d+)-?(\d+)? ?(\d|\w*)s?/g,(_,a,b,c)=>b?[for(i of Array(b-a--+1))if(++a*c?(b-a)%c<1:!c||a%2==c>'f')a].join`, `:a||'')
button.onclick=()=>output.innerHTML=F(range.value)
```

```css
button, textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="range"></textarea>
<button id="button">submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```